# Why is this template function fine when forward declared in MSVC

Tags: visual-c++

when compiling existing code using GCC i got the error `non-class, non-variable partial specialization ‘make_buffer<size>’ is not allowed`.

The boiled down code would look like (single cpp):

```
#include <array>
template <typename T, size_t size>
std::array<T, size> make_typed_buffer()
{
    return std::array<T, size>();
}

template <size_t size>
std::array<char, size> make_buffer();

template <size_t size>
std::array<char, size> make_buffer<size>()
{
    return make_typed_buffer<char, size>();
}
```

This code compiles fine with MSVC 19.29.30038.1 but not with GCC.

When i remove the forward declaration of the template function:

```
#include <array>
template <typename T, size_t size>
std::array<T, size> make_typed_buffer()
{
    return std::array<T, size>();
}

//template <size_t size>
//std::array<char, size> make_buffer();

template <size_t size>
std::array<char, size> make_buffer<size>()
{
    return make_typed_buffer<char, size>();
}
```

I get the error `unrecognizable template declaration/definition` (which is what i would have expected in the first place). Why is the compiler fine with the forward declaration but not without it, and maybe why is it even fine in the first place?

Thanks in advance, have a nice day :)

Comment: Is it an undocumented Microsoft extension?

Comment: @AdrianMole After reading https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/microsoft-extensions-to-c-and-cpp?view=msvc-160 i wonder if this could be part of `Use of benign typedef redefinitions within the same scope`